# Indexing numpy array not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am writing a function in which I want to store a 2 dimensional matrix as a subset of a larger 2 dimension matrix. All the code seems to be working correctly except that the result from einsum is not being stored in the matrix E (3rd to last line). Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
    def two_cycles(A):
        nonzeroSubset = np.diag(la.matrix_power(A,4) - la.matrix_power(A,2))
        x = np.argsort(nonzeroSubset)[:100]
        subset = A[x,:][:,x]

        n = len(A)
        E = np.zeros((n,n))

        E[x][:,x] = np.einsum('ij,ji->ij',subset,subset)
        fourCycles = np.array(np.nonzero(E)).T
        return fourCycles
```

Comment: Can you reduce your example program down to one that works in just two dimensions?  Might make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: I updated the example.

Comment: "E[x][:,x,:,:][:,:,x,:][:,:,:,x] = ..." - okay, you need to slow down and learn the advanced indexing rules. That's assigning to a copy of a copy of a copy of what you want to assign to.

Comment: `E[x][:,x]` feels like a really weird way to do this.  I'm guessing that the combination of the view and the index is causing a copy to be made so you're setting an element of the copy and not of `E`...

Comment: What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

```
 x = np.argsort(nonzeroSubset)[:100]
 ...
 E[x][:,x] = ....
```

So `x` is a list of indices.  That means `E[x]` uses advanced indexing and is a copy.  `E[...][...]` can return a useful value (as in `A[x,:][:,x]`), but does not work for assignment if the first index produces a copy.  In general, avoid, double brackets like that in `numpy`.  Instead figure out how to perform the desired indexing with one set of brackets (and multidimensional indexes).

Are you trying to assign to the values to the diagonal of `E` (in a particular order)?

Here's a way of both fetching and assigning to the diagonals of an array:

```
In [379]: A=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

In [380]: ind=np.diag_indices(3)

In [381]: ind
Out[381]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))

In [382]: A[ind]
Out[382]: array([0, 4, 8])

In [383]: A[ind]=[8,4,0]

In [384]: A
Out[384]: 
array([[8, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 0]])
```

---

I think that in your case this should work (but haven't tested it):

```
    x = np.argsort(nonzeroSubset)[:100]
    subset = A[x,x]   # diagonals of A in a sorted order
     ....
    E[x,x] = np.einsum('ij,ji->ij',subset,subset)
    # assignment to diagonal in the same order
```